# Prove: Expectation value is the weighted average

Tags: operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

How do we mathematically prove that the expectation value of an operator is the weighted average,

$$
\langle\hat{A}\rangle=\langle \psi|\hat{A}|\psi\rangle=\sum_{n}a_{n}P(a_{n}) \space \space \space?
$$

Let's say,

$\phi_{n}$ are the eigenvectors of the state, then

$\hat{A}|\phi_{n}\rangle=a_{n}|\phi_{n}\rangle$ and $P(a_{n})=|\langle\phi|\psi\rangle|^{2}$

Comment: It's not clear what you mean with the notation in the right hand side. Provide some context please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given some discrete spectrum of non-degenerated eigen-values/ eigenstates  $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ and $(|\phi_i\rangle)_{i\in I}$ associated to observable (hermitian operator) $\hat A$ one can decompose the state,

\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle = \sum_i |\phi_i\rangle
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\hat A|\psi\rangle = \sum_i \hat A|\phi_i\rangle = \sum_i a_i |\phi_i\rangle
\end{equation}

Considering an orthogonal basis eigenstates,
\begin{equation}
\langle \phi_i | \phi_k \rangle = \delta_{ik} \mathcal P(a_i)
\end{equation}

Then one gets,
\begin{equation}
\langle\psi|\hat A|\psi\rangle = \sum_{i,k} \langle\phi_i|\hat A|\phi_k\rangle = \sum_{i,k} a_k \langle\phi_i|\phi_k\rangle = \sum_i a_i \mathcal P(a_i)
\end{equation}

The last equality resulting from orthogonality.

The same holds for a continuous spectrum.